# Testing a class that uses the storage facade?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to unit test a function that calls another function that uses the storage facade. When I run the function in phpunit, it returns the error, "Error: Class 'Storage' not found." How can I run the function either without an error or defaulting the second function to return true?

Part of the code I am trying to test.

```
public function newMaterial($fileType, $groupId, $categoryId, $fileName, $file, $open, $close) {


    $material = new Mat;

    if (!$this->save($fileType, $file, $material)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the section of code that is causing the error.

```
protected function save($fileType, $file, Mat $material) {


    //generate random name
    do {
        $key = str_random(32);

        //check if exist
    } while (Storage::exists($path . $key . '.' . $ext));


    return true;
}
```

This is not all of my code, just the parts that are causing an issue.

In my test I am only calling the newMaterial Function and it returns the error.

Comment: Copy/paste your code here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.  We need to see your test case as well and any other relevant code or we end up guessing which tends to not be helpful.